Javascript Game playing TOO FAST on M1 MacBook Pro
I just made a little "Space Invaders" game using plain vanilla Javascript and it's running beautifully on my 2018 MacMini -- but ridiculously and blazingly fast on my 2021 MacBook Pro (which has the M1 chip in it.)
Since I'm using requestAnimationFrame() for my main animation loop (as opposed to setInerval), I have full control and went ahead and throttled the animation's frame-rate WAAAY down, literally taking it from 60fps down to 10fps -- but it's STILL running prohibitively fast on the M1 MacBook Pro.
I know my particular M1 MacBook Pro has a screen refresh rate of 120Hz - which might be the biggest culprit and main cause of the problem here, but if so, how do I work around this?
Would appreciate any and all tips and advice.
Thank you.

You should use code that allows you to control timing more precisely, such as setTimeout() and setInterval().

I read a bunch of posts saying requestAnimationFrame() is a much better option than setInterval() because it's more accurate, takes up less memory, etc.  Can't recall all the reasons, but the overall consensus was that it's a much much better way to go. Like I've seen this in not just one or two places, but everywhere.  So what makes you say this?

Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example that we can work with.

Yes, requestAnimationFrame() is indeed a much better option for animation. You just need to take into account the actual time that has passed between two invocations. Then, for example, given speed and delta-time, you can calculate distance.
Here's a very simplistic example, you can find more about "the game loop" or similiar term, online.


var dt, last
var speed = 0.2;
var totalDistance = 0
var maxDistance = 300

function frame(now) {
  dt = last ? now - last : 0

  update(dt)
  render(dt)

  last = now;
  requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}


function update(dt) {
  totalDistance += dt * speed;
  if (totalDistance >= maxDistance || totalDistance <= 0) {
    speed *= -1
  }
  totalDistance = Math.max(Math.min(maxDistance, totalDistance), 0)
}

function render(dt) {
  element.style.transform = `translateX(${totalDistance}px)`;
}

requestAnimationFrame(frame);
#element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
<div id="element">Hello</div>




OK I'm already doing some of this: I've already got code that's calculating the exact number of milliseconds that have transpired between each invocation of requestAnimationFrame(),  & I'm making sure to NOT render another Frame if that time is UNDER my desired 16.6667ms, cause that means it's going TOO FAST (and I do know that this much IS working) - BUT...I'll have a look at ur code and see if ur doing anything different. I will say that the total-distance that my Space Invaders need to travel has to be Fixed (I'm pretty sure), so I don't know if I want that to be recalculated each time...
